# Scala function TypeTag: T use type T in function

Tags: scala

I need to parse several json fields, which I'm using Play Json to do it. As parsing may fail, I need to throw a custom exception for each field.

To read a field, I use this:

`val fieldData = parseField[String](json \ fieldName, "fieldName")`

My parseField function:

```
def parseField[T](result: JsLookupResult, fieldName: String): T = {
    result.asOpt[T].getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"""Can't access $fieldName."""))
}
```

However, I get an error that reads:

> Error:(17, 17) No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement
>   an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
>       result.asOpt[T].getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"""Can't access $fieldName."""))

Is there a way to tell the `asOpt[]` to use the type in `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you do not throw exceptions. The Play JSON API has both a `JsSuccess` and `JsError` types that will help you encode parsing errors.

As per the documentation

> To convert a Scala object to and from JSON, we use `Json.toJson[T: Writes]` and `Json.fromJson[T: Reads]` respectively. Play JSON provides the Reads and Writes typeclasses to define how to read or write specific types. You can get these either by using Play's automatic JSON macros, or by manually defining them. You can also read JSON from a `JsValue` using `validate`, `as` and `asOpt` methods. Generally it's preferable to use validate since it returns a `JsResult` which may contain an error if the JSON is malformed.

See https://github.com/playframework/play-json#reading-and-writing-objects

There is also [a good example on the Play Discourse forum](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/exception-handling-in-play-framework-parsing-json/625) on how the API manifests in practice.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I went with this option using `validate`. This brought another question, but I think it goes to another post. Thanks.